# How to handle struct initialization in systemverilog

Tags: c, system-verilog

I have the code as below but it failed at compile error.

```
typedef struct {
    logic [7:0] mem_data[1024];
} mem_blk;

mem_blk m_mem[];
...
...
logic [7:0] data = 'h12;
m_mem[3].mem_data[0] = data;
```

the error information is :
Error- [SV-RTOOBAW] Reference to out of bound array word

Comment: Is it supposed to be a test bench code or an rtl code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic arrays need to be allocated using `new[]`, or a copy from an array of the same time. So you need to do

```
m_mem = new[4];
```

Before you can reference `m_mem[3]`.

Or maybe you meant to declare an associative array instead of a dynamic array.

```
mem_blk m_mem[bit [15:0]];
```

Then a write to `m_mem[3]` allocates that entry.